# Change file location in System.Runtime.Caching file cache

Tags: c#, caching

Can we change the default file location when using `System.Runtime.Caching.FileCache` class? `FileCache.CacheDir` is readonly property.

By default it creates cache file under .....\bin\debug\cache. The reason I need this to be customised is because the web api runs under a service account which doesnt have write access to this file's location.

I know that we can grant read write access to the service account but thats something is not possible. Any thoughts will be really helpful.

Comment: What is `System.Runtime.Caching.FileCache`? That isn't in the .Net Framework so it must be an external library.

Comment: FileCache can be added via NuGet package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [.Net File Cache](https://fc.codeplex.com/) library, looking at the [source code](https://fc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/FileCache/FileCache.cs), it has a few different constructors, some of which expose a parameter called `cacheRoot`. So you just need to change which constructor you are using. For example:

```
var fileCache = new FileCache(@"c:\yourdirectory");
```